# Подсчет количества юзеров прошедших редирект на javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Всем привет. Есть необходимость вести подсчет количества юзеров, прошедших редирект. Плюс нужно, при достижении определенного количества прошедших редирект, заменять ссылку целевой страницы на другую.
Желательно реализовать на javascript/jquery. Может, кто подскажет готовую реализацию?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На `javascript/jquery` не реализуете никак, так как он исполняется у одного конкретного юзера, а вам юзеров надо на бэкенде считать

Comment: @Oleg Ну теоретически  можно заставить javascript анализировать выданное сервером количество сделанных редиректов до того (Значение в javascript подставлять как в шаблон, например :) ). Вопрос в том, зачем городить такой огород :)

Comment: Где то был вопрос по рендерингу переменных в javascript на django. Делается легко, но в данном случае не понятно зачем  такое делать в принципе.

Comment: Ну ок, получил редиректнутый клиент, что он последний, кто мог перейти по этой ссылке. Что ему дальше делать в этой замечательной информацией? =)